# Render rails fields_for through ajax call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I have an AJAX call:

```
$('#enrollment_members').change(function(){
var memberNumber = $(this);
$.ajax({type: 'GET',
      url: $(this).href,
      type: "get",
      data: { members: memberNumber.val() },
      error: function(){ alert("There was a problem, please try again.") }
      });
return false;

console.log(data);
});
```

through which I send params[:members] into a new method.

I wanna do something like this:

```
def new
  @enrollment = Enrollment.new
  params[:members] ? params[:members].to_i.times { @enrollment.atendees.build } : @enrollment.atendees.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

I need this value in order to know how many `fields_for` to build.

But this being in the new action, how can I update the content of the new view after inputting a value in the `members` input field?

From that ternary, @enrollment.atendees contains 4 objects.

My `new.js.erb` :

```
$("#contact-wrap").html("<%= j render(:partial => 'enrollments/form') %>");
```

The xhr response contains 4 `fields_for` forms.

Comment: It is not really clear what your goals are. Do you want to add fields dynamically to an HTML form through an AJAX call ?

Comment: @CyrilDD I edited my question, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by modifying the ajax call:

```
$('#enrollment_members').change(function(){
var memberNumber = $(this);
$.ajax({type: 'GET',
      url: $(this).href,
      type: "get",
      dataType : "html",
      data: { members: memberNumber.val() },
        success: function( data ) {
          var result = $('<div />').append(data).find('#contact-wrap').html();
          $('#contact-wrap').html(result);
          $('#atendees-wrap').show();
        },
        error: function( xhr, status ) {
          alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" );
        }
      });
return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the object `#enrollment_members` the input value you are trying to pass to the controller?

if so, try this:

```
$('#enrollment_members').change(function(){
  var memberNumber = $(this);
  $.ajax({type: 'GET',
    url: $(this).href,
    type: "get",
    data: { members: memberNumber.serialize() }, //CHANGE
    error: function(){ 
      alert("There was a problem, please try again.") 
    }
});
return false;
```

Comment: it's a bit unclear on what should change here.. right now, a single form shows, and I want to build a 'members' number of forms after setting a value to the members input field. like re-render the new page with the members params.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer to reflect the line that has changed.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The problem is not that it doesn't send the param. I've edited my question to make it a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm are you really sure you need a custom made solution for this ? The behavior of dynamically adding/removing children in `fields_for` is already adressed by several gems like [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) (no longer maintained) or [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) (more promising)

I'd suggest to actually reuse their library even if you need to tweak it your way. Because doing an AJAX request is completely pointless. Your AJAX is a GET request that will always do the same thing, unless you have a custom `atendees.build` which will do weird things for successive calls (like incrementing a global counter somewhere).

Those gems I mentionned above will actually save the HTML fields to generate in a "template" (stored locally in HTML or JS), and just call this template when you want to add a new field.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. but can you give me a few hints on how to solve the problem described in the question? Maybe I'll bump into this on a custom update or something. Basically I just need to re-render the new view with the xhr response.